# Is there a way to make my outlook add-in page load as a pop up instead of displaying on the side pane?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an outlook add-in, and it loads on the side pane instead of a pop up. I've seen "share to teams" add-in loads as a pop up. Note: My add-in is similar to "share to teams" add-in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui) to display a dialog window instead of task panes. Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

For example, by clicking on the ribbon button you can call the [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) method to display a popup window.